# twitter bootstrap thumbnails as list items

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have http://jsfiddle.net/EGyKe/.

The thumbnails in the second row are not well suited as what I want. I dont want to declare multiple rows. However want to add more `<li>` to add more thumbnails.

Comment: Why not take out the 'row-fluid'? http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/EGyKe/5/

Comment: @Skelly Thank you very much. You should have just written it in answer, and I would have accepted it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

To this:

```
<div class="row">
```

...and you should be golden.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails